# Open ball around a set is open

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(E,d)$ be a metric space, $A\subseteq E$ and $r>0$. Can we show that $$C:=\left\{x\in E:d(x,A)<r\right\}$$ is open? Or do we need to assume that $A$ is closed/open?

Intuitively, the claim is rather trivial if we think about $A$ as a sufficiently nice set.

By definition of the infimum, we know that $$\forall x\in E:\forall\varepsilon>0:\exists a\in A:0\le d(x,a)-d(x,A)<\varepsilon\tag1.$$

If $x\in C$, we need to show that there is a $\varepsilon>0$ such that $B_\varepsilon(x)\subseteq C$. How can we do that or what do we need to assume to show that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $d(x,A) <r$ and $d(x,y) <r-d(x,A)$  then $d(y,A) \leq d(x,A)+d(x,y) <r$.  So $B(x,r-d(x,A)) \subseteq C$.

Answer (score 5):

$d(x,A)<r$ iff there exists $a\in A$ such that $d(x,a)<r$ so $B(A,r)=\bigcup_{a\in A}B(a,r)$, since arbitrary union of open sets is an open set we have that $B(A,r)$ is open.

Answer (score 0):

Consider an arbitrary metric space $(X, d)$. For arbitrary nonempty subset $\varnothing \neq M \subseteq X$ and for arbitrary $x, y \in X$ the relation $|d(x, M)-d(y, M)| \leqslant d(x, y)$ is valid. On these grounds it is easy to establish the continuity of the following map:
$$\begin{align}
f \colon X &\to [0, \infty)\\
f(x) &= d(x, M).
\end{align}$$
For given $\rho>0$ it is obvious that $\{x \in X \mid d(x, M)<\rho\}=f^{-1}[[0, \rho)]$ and your claim follows immediately since obviously $[0, \rho)$ is *open* in the relative topology of $[0, \infty)$ (which is none other than the order topology on this positive semiaxis).